# Laravel eloquent json in select query

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am writing a database query which returns a 'json' column which I am generating using mysql `CONCAT` function.

My select query looks like this:

```
$results->selectRaw("CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT('value', measured_at, 'day', datediff(measurements.measured_at, athletes.tracking_started_at))), ']') as `values`");
```

However my response is escaped like this:

```
"values": "[{\"value\": \"2018-09-03 00:00:00.000000\", \"day\": 0}]"
```

Can I select this as json so that I get a json response and not a string?

Comment: AFAIK database returning data is always either string or numerical. But you can use `json_decode()` on the string to convert it. (Perhaps inside a Laravel attribute cast if appropriate here.)

Comment: Instead of using concat to merge strings can you try `JSON_ARRAY` ? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-array